# How to implement db capability approach with pure functions in F#?

Tags: functional-programming, f#, pure-function

I have a code sample like this:

```
type Db = 
    | Db of Map<string, string>

let get id db =   
    let (Db dict) = db
    dict
    |> Map.tryFind id
    |> (fun x -> x, db)
    
let add id value db =
    let (Db dict) = db
    dict
    |> Map.add id value
    |> Db
    |> (fun x -> (), x)

let remove id db =
    let (Db dict) = db
    dict
    |> Map.remove id
    |> Db
    |> (fun x -> (), x)

type GetByIdCapability =
    | GetByIdCapability of ? (Id -> Value * ?) ?

type AddValueCapability =
    | AddValueCapability of ? (Id -> Value -> ?) ?

type RemoveByIdCapability =
    | RemoveByIdCapability of ? (Id -> ?) ?

type CreateAddValueCapability =
    | CreateAddValueCapability of (Db -> AddValueCapability)

type AddValueService =
    {
        AddValueCapability: AddValueCapability
    }

let createAddValueService db (CreateAddValueCapability createAddValueCapabilityFunc) =
    let addValueCapability = db |> createAddValueCapabilityFunc
    {
        AddValueCapability = addValueCapability
    }

let addValue id value (addValueService: AddValueService) =
    addValueService.AddValueCapability ?
```

What I want is to have `AddValueService` which must have access only to "add value to Db" capability and has no access to other functions of Db inside service's logic. But at the same time I want to get updated instance of Db after calling service's logic. Is it possible to implement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can define your *Db* API in a separate module, and the capabilities like this:

```
type AddValueCapability =
    private AddValueCapability of (string -> string -> Db -> unit * Db)

let addValueCapability = AddValueCapability add

let runAddValue (AddValueCapability f) = f
```

Notice that the `AddValueCapability` type has a `private` case constructor, which means that no code outside of the defining module can pattern-match on it.

The `addValueCapability` value is the only way external client code can get a hold of a value of that type. You may or may not want to export that value as well, depending on your exact needs.

While external client code can't pattern-match on the `AddValueCapability` case constructor, it can run the capability using the `runAddValue` function.

Here's a simple example of a function that is defined *outside* of the *Db* module:

```
let useCapability (cap : AddValueCapability) db =
    runAddValue cap "foo" "bar" db
```

It can run the capability, but not anything else if you also lock down the underlying functionality:

```
let private get id db =   
    let (Db dict) = db
    dict
    |> Map.tryFind id
    |> (fun x -> x, db)
    
let private add id value db =
    let (Db dict) = db
    dict
    |> Map.add id value
    |> Db
    |> (fun x -> (), x)

let private remove id db =
    let (Db dict) = db
    dict
    |> Map.remove id
    |> Db
    |> (fun x -> (), x)
```

Here's an xUnit.net demo of it:

```
[<Fact>]
let Demo () =
    let db = Map.empty |> Db
    let _, actual = useCapability addValueCapability db
    Assert.Equal (Map.ofList ["foo", "bar"] |> Db, actual)
```

You can create other capabilities in a similar fashion, and pass only those capabilities around that you want client code to have...

...or you could just define some single-method interfaces and pass those around to client code. That's how you'd usually do it in OOD.